# What means laserRetro in Gazebo

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I'm not able to find documentation for parameter "laserRetro" of Gazebo world file. I saw this parameter in some file, but I'm not sure what exactly it means.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30472/what-means-laserretro-in-gazebo/) by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 704 on 2012-03-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In electric, a `<laserRetro>` element can be declared under gazebo's `<geom:xxx>` element, and was used to set the [LaserScan](http://ros.org/doc/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html) `intensities` field when a simulated ray hits a surface.  As pointed out by PKG, this is not correct, but an extreme simplification.  This feature should be improved in Fuerte with the upcoming GPU version of laser range scanners currently being constructed.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-04-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This may be a slightly inaccurate answer. From  this  [PlayerStage page](http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/doc/Gazebo-manual-svn-html/classgazebo_1_1Geom.html) it's clear that retro Laser refers to the reflectiveness of the surface in question. From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroreflector) it's clear that a RetroReflector  reflects light back with minimum scattering, much like reflectors on roads.

Summing up, I feel that laser retro measures the extent to which the material reflects laser light with minimal scattering. The notion of laser retro reflectiveness also makes sense , e.g. see [here](http://www.keyence.com/topics/sensors/lv/reflect.php).

---

Originally posted by [PKG](https://answers.ros.org/users/671/pkg/) with karma: 365 on 2012-04-03

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2012-04-03**:
Thanks for answer...